# Casting to interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the following snippet

```
let x = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 30
}

interface Employee {
    name:string,
}

let y:Employee = <Employee>x;

console.log(y); //y still have the age property, why
```

Why typescript ignores this casting, and is there other solution to get those interface properties only ?

Comment: I know that interface in typescript is for type checking and it only used by compiler, but I think it should be a way to accomplish this without creating classes, right ?

Answer (score 2):

Casting (or more correctly a type assertion) will not change anything about the object at runtime, it will just inform the compiler about the type of the object at compile time so that the compiler can do type checks.

Moreover, in this case you don't need a type assertion, this code will work just as well:

```
let y:Employee = x;
```

Typescript will give an error on extra properties, only if you directly assign an object literal to a variable typed as `Employee`, but if you have a variable that is typed to a type that satisfies the `Employee` interface but has some extra properties, the assignment is considered valid. Anyone accessing `y` will have access to the `Employee` fields and will ignore the rest which will not be a problem.

If you want to have an object with only the fields of `Employee` you will need to create it:

```
let y:Employee = { name: x.name };
//OR
let { age, ...y } = x;
```

Comment: Yea, yet the "y" object will still have all properties of x if I do let y:Employee=x .. that what I think is not convenient

Comment: @MustafaMagdy in most cases you should not care about those fields, if you access the object through `y` you will never have access to them, if you do through the keys of the object, then you might consider one of the two options to create a new object with just those fields..